# Visual-Positioning Method

Tags: manipulator, opencv, visual-servoing

I'm working on mobile manipulator and trying to do visual-positioning of the end-effector.

[image]

My camera will located around 1-2 meters from the robot. 
I'm sure i cant use color tracking method because the color of end-effector not unique to the environment and i can't get the orientation of end-effector. If I'm using neural network, the computation cost will high (not reliable for high-speed control). What method of visual-positioning can i use for this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it sounds like you have an external camera system to track the end effector position and orientation?

In that case I would use QR codes or [april tags](https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltag). Stick a couple of these on your end effector, and make sure that you put enough of them that 1 is always visible from your camera. The apriltags library provides the ability to extract position and orientation.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.. i will try using it